# Big O of Ugly Numbers Algorithm (Brute force method)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, proof

Link to problem: [Ugly Numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/)

How would you find the Big O of the brute force (Simple Method Approach) solution for Ugly-Numbers.

I see that for this part of the code:

```
    /* Function to check if a number is ugly or not */
int isUgly(int no) 
{ 
  no = maxDivide(no, 2); 
  no = maxDivide(no, 3); 
  no = maxDivide(no, 5); 

  return (no == 1)? 1 : 0; 
}
```

Each step takes `log_2(x) + log_3(x) + log_5(x)` steps, where `x = no`

So this would mean the runtime is **(log_2(x) + log_3(x) + log_5(x))<sup>n</sup>** where x is the result of the output. However, the result of an algorithm can't be a part of the Big O notation right? If it can't, this would be reduced to **c<sup>n</sup>** right? Where **c > result**. What is the proper method of proof for this?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of *isUgly* method is **O(log N)**, where N is the input. Because the complexity of *maxDivide* is **O(log N)** and calling that function a fixed amount of times (3 in this case) does not change the complexity.

> However, the result of an algorithm can't be a part of the Big O notation right?

Yes, the result of a function is irrelevant while calculating the complexity of that function.

The time complexity of the getNthUglyNo is unknown or ~infinite! For N=500 it runes 937500 times!

Comment: isUgly can be called more than N times though, so it wouldn't be `O(N log N)`. N is simply the counter target for the amount of "Ugly numbers found". isUgly is called i amount of times (which can be infinite) until `counter == N`

I think you missed the part of the code for when `count++` gets called in `getNthUglyNo` function. Count is not incremented for each iteration of that `while (n > count) ` loop so that while loop actually runs more than N times therefore isUgly gets called more than N times.

Comment: ah! my apology, I didn't read that code properly - it is kind of like an infinite loop!

Comment: `getNthUglyNo`'s complexity is certainly finite, in the sense that it terminates for all inputs (ignoring range limits on the integers used), because there are obviously infinitely many numbers that are *ugly*.

Comment: So is the Big O of this infinity? DDDDD:

Answer (score 0):

*Ugly numbers* are also also known as *regular numbers*. As you can see [from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_number), it is known that the number of regular numbers up to `m` is

```
(ln(m*sqrt(30))^3 / (6*ln(2)*ln(3)*ln(5)) + O(ln(m))
```

In other words, your `getNthUglyNo` will call `isUgly` to get the `n`-th regular number

```
~ 1/sqrt(30) * exp((n*6*ln(2)*ln(3)*ln(5))^(1/3))
```

times.

The probability that a uniform random integer number `x` between `0` and `M` is divisible by `2^y` is asymptotically`1/2^y` and so the mean number of times that the loop in the call `maxDivide(no, 2);` iterates is `O(1)` and equivalently for `maxDivide(no, 3);` and `maxDivide(no, 5);`.

Consequently your algorithm is

```
Theta( exp((n*6*ln(2)*ln(3)*ln(5))^(1/3)) )
```

which is approximately

```
Theta( exp(1.9446 * n^(1/3)) )
```

---

Also note that plugging in `n = 500` into the asymptotic number of iterations mentioned above does give you `921498`, which is pretty close to the number of iterations @sowrov found in their answer (`937500`).